# Como declarar uma variável do tipo data no Postgress

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, query

Eu preciso declarar uma variável do tipo DATA que vai receber a data atual - 31 dias no postgress, mas não consigo, eu sei como faz no sql server dessa forma abaixo

```
DECLARE @DATA DATE
SET @DATA = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DD, -31, GETDATE()),120))
```

e na hora que eu for utilizar é só eu fazer isso aqui é só chamar a variavel com o @...

```
WHERE DATA_PGTO > @DATA
```

Me ajudem como fazer isso no POSTGRESS.

Já tentei tirar o @ do @DATA, já tentei utilizar data type @DATA..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

WHERE DATA_PGTO > CURRENT_DATE
da pra aplicar filtros mais precisos também

WHERE DATA_PGTO >= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' day);

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).